# Firebug identified xpath not working in protractor

Tags: node.js, xpath, automation, protractor

Firebug identified xpath not working in protractor.I ahve cretaed xpath using firebug.When I identify the xpath using IDE,it is working fine.However when I use the same xpath in protractor,it is not working.My element does not have id or name.So here i can use only xpath option.

Please find the below image for reference.
Here I need to verify whether that particular element has "IRCTC Attractions" text.

Could you please help me?

HTML code:

```
//div style="width:100%;" class="g_hedtext">IRCTC Attractions /div
```

Comment: What XPath expression did you use? And when you say it's not working, do you mean that it selects nothing? Selects the wrong element? Throws an error? What is the error message?

Comment: I have identified xpath using firebug.When verify the element using IDE or fire-path that particular element working fine.But when I use same xpath in protractor it is throwing error ad element not found.

Comment: What XPath expression did you use?

Comment: @LarsH.. I have used the xpath xpression which is identified by firebug.When i identify the element using the xpath expression via firebug or IDE,it is working fine.But when we use same xpath in protractor it is throwing error as "Unexpected Identifier".                                                              xpath=(//div[@id='option-item-1']/div/div/span)[2]

Comment: OK, so your XPath expression seems to be `(//div[@id='option-item-1']/div/div/span)[2]`. I don't see an unexpected identifier there, so I would guess the problem is something else in how you're using Protractor. Can you give us more context showing how you're using the XPath in Protractor?

Comment: @LarsH  var Someoption = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="option-item-1"]/div/div[2]/span'));

function Stopclock-Validation()
{
expect(Someoption.getText()).toEqual('vibrant');

};

When I execute this, in the command window protractor saying "Unexpected Identifier"

Failures:
1) Exception loading: 
SyntaxError: C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\TC_model2.js:7
var disclaimermessage = element(by.xpath('//[@id='disclaimer-message']'));
^^^^^^^^^^
Unexpected identifier
Stacktrace:
var disclaimermessage = element(by.xpath('//[@id='disclaimer-message']'));

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, looking at your error message (in the comment):

```
Exception loading: SyntaxError:
C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\TC_model2.js:7
var disclaimermessage = element(by.xpath('//[@id='disclaimer-message']'));
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^ Unexpected identifier
```

(I'm guessing where the carets before "Unexpected identifier" were aligned. Is that right?)

The problem is that you've used single quotes both to delimit the string `'disclaimer-message'`, and to delimit the whole XPath expression `'//[@id='disclaimer-message']'`. Thus it appears to the parser that your XPath expression is the stuff between the first two single quotes: `'//[@id='`, and then the `disclaimer-message` is some other identifier without any comma or other operator to show what it's doing there.

The solution is to use double quotes inside the XPath expression. XPath accepts either single or double quotes; it doesn't care, as long as you match them with each other. So change the offending line to

```
var disclaimermessage = element(by.xpath('//[@id="disclaimer-message"]'));
```

And you should be good to go.

For future reference, this question would have been quicker and easier to answer if you had told us about the error message in the first place.

Comment: Relative xpath things r not workng in protractor.Selenium we can create xpath using contains method.Using this contains xpath we can identify objects in the selenium webdriver.When we use the same xpath in protractor it is throwing error as
"NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.xpath(xpath=//img[contains(@src,"images/splash-you-text.png")]).

When I use the same xpath in IDE,it is working fine.Please let me know your comments.comments. Attached screenshot for reference.
https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/13692001/9244122/d859c246-41b5-11e5-9f3f-c4dde62c8449.png

Comment: @ManojSoundarrajan: Is this a new question, or the same problem still? What happened when you tried fixing the quotes like I described above? I don't see any relative XPath expressions in what you wrote. A relative XPath expression doesn't start with `/`. Is your screenshot of Selenium IDE or Protractor?

Comment: As you said double quoted xpaths working fine.Thanks for that answer.One more question related to relative xpath,we can create xpaths using contains,text kind of stuffs.Above xpath I have created using contains method. When I use this xpath in IDE it is working fine.However when I use the same xpath in protractor it is throwing error.//img[contains(@src,"images/splash-you-text.png") this is my xpath value,starts with //.My screenshot refers Selenium IDE object identification using relative xpath.

Comment: @ManojSoundarrajan: If I answered the original question in a way that solved your problem, please consider checking the checkmark to "accept" the answer. I'm not sure why Protractor isn't finding your element. You may want to post a whole new question, to get other eyes on it besides mine. Regarding relative XPath: an expression that starts with `//` also starts with `/`, so it's not relative.

Answer (score 1):

Find the element by text and assert it's present:

```
var elm = element(by.xpath("//div[. = 'IRCTC Attractions']"));
expect(browser.isElementPresent(elm)).toBe(true);
```

Comment: We should use xpath with double quotes (") to eliminate the error.