# Protractor: path relative from the element

Tags: angularjs, xpath, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I want to write something like:

```
return component.element(by.xpath('//div/div/a')); // I want: path to component + xpath
```

But I always have the result same with:

```
return element(by.xpath('//div/div/a'));   // I always have: just xpath
```

Component is an element that was found with my own locator:

```
component = element(by.Name('Component_name'));
```

What I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please also add information about what is a component.

Comment: @Michael Radionov I edited question.

Comment: There must be some Protractor documentation that is giving people the impression that XPath expressions starting with `//` are "relative paths." The questioner at http://stackoverflow.com/q/31884964/423105 has the some mistaken understanding. Can you tell us where you read about "relative XPaths" so we can get it corrected? Did you get this from http://seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/xpath-tutorial-for-selenium?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it is because of the selector for xpath locator. When you use expression starting with `//`, it will look for any element on the page, even if you use it with parent element. There is a note about it in the docs for [xpath locator](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.By.xpath):

> For example, given the selector "//div", WebDriver will search from
>   the document root regardless of whether the locator was used with a
>   WebElement.

It can be fixed by putting a dot before double slash: `.//div/div/a`, which should make a search relative to parent element.

Take a look at [xpath spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev), to find more info.